# How to shrink an image to fit within a header in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I am trying to include an image that has the following dimensions :
Width  450 pixels
Height 250 pixels
In the left corner of a header that has the height of
height: 60px;
However it does not stay within the header div, I can't even see the header div after the outline was added. My intention is to shrink it to be fit within the header and yet still be able to maintain its aspect ratio. Below is the style applied:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*----------------------------------------------
                                  header
              ----------------------------------------------*/

.header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  /* Medium blue */
  font-family: Nirmala UI;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: #3300FF dashed;
}

.header .imageframe img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 15em;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="imageframe" id="imageFrame">
    <img src="images/TMone_Full_H.png" alt="TM One logo">
  </div>
  <!-- END imageFrame -->
</div>
<!-- END header -->
<div class='midfield'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class="sidebarNavContainer">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-list-buttons">
          <a id="shellmenu_0" class="fa-nav-list-buttons-link" href="https://products.office.com/EN/home">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-list-buttons">
          <a id="shellmenu_0" class="fa-nav-list-buttons-link" href="https://products.office.com/EN/home">REVENUE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END of sidebarNavContainer -->
  </div>
  <!-- END of sidebar -->
  <div class='content'>

  </div>
  <!-- END of content -->
</div>
<!-- END of midfield -->
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are using `object-fit: cover` which will expand the image until it covers it's entire container.

To resize an image to fit inside it's container and keep it's aspect-ratio you can  use `object-fit: contain` or `object-fit: scale-down`.

You can read more about this CSS property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Comment: I have just tried them both but it just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the code declares the "header" with an id="header". The CSS that I had defined calls the div with a class selector. I am sorry for bothering everyone. The problem was already settled as soon as I had found this out. Thanks for all who answered.